# How add trailing slash in URl for 2 or more directories?

Tags: url, nginx, slash, subdirectory

nginx server 
I am having a problem adding a trailing slash if I have two or more subdirectories

```
rewrite ^/([^.]*[^/])$ $1/ permanent; //this is working example if I have one directory
```

How can I add a trailing slash if I have two or more subdirectories?

http://example.com/foo/foo2/
http://example.com/foo/foo2/

Answer (score 0):

Capture everything not with a trailing slash and add a trailing slash to it.

```
rewrite ^(.*[^/])$ $1/ permanent;
```